# Run sed remotely via SSH: Probably quoting issue

Tags: bash, ssh, sed

I want to do a substitution in /etc/bashrc remotely via SSH on multiple hosts.

```
ssh myhost sed 's/\\u\@\\h/\\u\@\\h (myhost)/' /etc/bashrc
```

gives me this error:

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `sed s/\\u\@\\h/\\u\@\\h (myhost)/ /etc/bashrc'
```

It runs without error directly on myhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single quotes are removed by the local shell, so that the remote host sees the following command line:

```
sed s/\\u\@\\h/\\u\@\\h (myhost)/ /etc/bashrc
```

You need an extra layer of quoting on the local side, which requires extra escaping of the backslashes as well.

```
ssh myhost "sed 's/\\\\u\\@\\\\h/\\\\u\\@\\\\h (myhost)/' /etc/bashrc"
```

Comment: You have to escape the \ if you use double quotes: `"sed 's/\\\\u\\@...`

Comment: Ugh, I was afraid of that.

Answer (score -1):

try adding

> (

before the brackets also you don't have to use:

```
 sed 's/something/another/'
```

you can use anything like:

```
 sed 's:something:another:'
 sed 's|something|another|'
```

or a few others to do the separation which gets rid of having to use backslashes for when using

> //folder/